# data not fetching from firestore in react native

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i created a collection in firestore called user and added a document and gave it 7 fields, but when i try fetching the data back using `onSnapshot` it does not return back any data. this is the collection

[image]

this is my code:

```
firestore()
          .collection('user')
          .doc('LCqSZXM17WUWiWFahyj6')
          .onSnapshot((row) => {
            console.log(row.data());
          });
```

in the console it logs an empty array

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include more information.
Anyway, do you check your access rule of the Firestore database?

```js
const doc = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');

const observer = doc.onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {
  console.log(`Received doc snapshot: ${docSnapshot}`);
  // ...
}, err => {
  console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
});
```

The above code is official docs code. Check error callback first.